# Flask-Restful routes showing 404

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm facing an issue where by in My Flask-Restful app, all the routes show `404 not found` when I try to navigate too them. for example `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login`.

In my App, all the routes are defined well but for some unclear reason all of them show 404.
Upon searching for an answer to this, I came across this question [Flask-Restful powered API returning 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280217/flask-restful-powered-api-returning-404-errors) but it was of no answer to my Issue. I don't know why this happens

Here is how I configured everything.
entry file app.py

```py
from api import create_app, db, jwt
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import MigrateCommand


app = create_app()

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all(app=create_app())
    app.run()
```

`__init__.py in auth folder`

```py
from .resources import UserLogin, LogoutAccess, TokenRefresh, LogoutRefresh, RegisterUser

def auth_routes(api):
    api.add_resource(UserLogin, '/auth/login')
    api.add_resource(RegisterUser, '/auth/register')
    api.add_resource(LogoutAccess, '/auth/logout')
    api.add_resource(TokenRefresh, '/auth/refresh')
    api.add_resource(LogoutRefresh, '/auth/logout/refresh')
```

`__init__.py in api folder`

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from .config import env_config
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging

convention = {
    "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
    "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
    "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
    "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
    "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=convention)

db = SQLAlchemy(metadata=metadata)
migrate = Migrate()
ma = Marshmallow()
api = Api()
jwt = JWTManager()
cors = CORS()

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

def create_app(config_name='testing'):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(env_config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    ma.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)
    jwt.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app)
    api.prefix = '/api/v1'
    
    from .errors.handlers import errors
    app.register_blueprint(errors)

    from models import RevokedToken

    @jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
    def check_if_token_in_blacklist(decrypted_token):
        jti = decrypted_token['jti']
        return RevokedToken.is_jti_blacklisted(jti)

    
    @jwt.user_claims_loader
    def add_claims_to_access_token(identity):
        return {
            'id': identity.id,
            'role': identity.role
        }

    @jwt.user_identity_loader
    def user_identity_lookup(user):
        return user.id

    from .auth import auth_routes
    from .parcels import parcel_routes

    auth_routes(api)
    parcel_routes(api)

        
    return app
```

I'm using python 3.9, Flask 1.12, Flask-RestFul 0.3.8

[image: 404 error when I hit login endpoint]

Comment: I can imagine that api.prefix = '/api/v1' doesn't actually work, did you try calling /api/auth/login without the prefix and check if you get a response?

Comment: You should have a look at [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/). Instead of `api.prefix`, you usually create a blueprint with a prefix and register the routes on that blueprint instead of `api` directly. Lastly, you register the blueprint in `api`.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 I removed the prefix and still the same

Answer (score 1):

If you're using app factory, you need to add resources before calling `api.init_app(app)`.

So:

1. `api = Api()`
2. `auth_routes(api)`
3. `api.init_app(app)`

That should do the trick as it did for me just now. Also, for others looking into this, you can view current routes in the app by:

In flask shell: `from flask import current_app` and running `current_app.url_map`